# Angular UI bootstrap typeahead ng-model says null when clear the filed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

The filter works very well, but unfortunately the `{{filterlist.name}}` says null once removed the typed text and also tables looks empty because of `null`

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/1QVdctw1hr4ggJOtFHUZ?p=preview

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" 
  ng-model="filterlist.name" 
  typeahead-editable="false" 
  uib-typeahead="person.name as person.name for person in expenses | filter:{name:$viewValue} | limitTo:8">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **[Updated Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/zAoA1iovcu0EQBctredX?p=preview)**

I think you missed to declare the `filterlist` in the `controller`

```
$scope.filterlist = { name: '' };
```

I have put the `{{}}` part at the top of the table just for readability.
*Not sure why it was an issue for you. Works in Chrome for me*